# 2x2 binary combinations and relevant binary image using Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Intention is to create all possible combination of 2x2 binary array filled with 1's and 0's and create relevant image for each array and store it as individual image.

Effort so far:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
lst = list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=4))
print (lst)
plt.imshow(lst)
plt.show()
```

Current Output:

[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]

[image: Binary output]

Expected output:

```
00
00  

00
01

and so on
```

More importantly to save those array as individual .png images For 2x2 array it would be 16 images in this example format.

```
10
01
```

[image: Sample example]

Help!

Edit1:

In higher matrix  saving throws a runtime error it can be solved by adding

```
plt.close(fig)
```

within the for statement

RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing, graphing, and saving:

```
for c,i in enumerate(lst):
    print(i[0],i[1],'\n',i[2],i[3],'\n',sep='')
    array = np.reshape(i,(2,2))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
    ax.imshow(array, cmap='gray')
    ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
    fig.savefig('figure_{}.png'.format(c))
    plt.close(fig)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape each element of the list by doing this

```
binary_images = [np.reshape(np.asarray(l), (2,2)) for l in lst]
```

and then save the images by using matplotlib

```
for i in binary_images:
    plt.imshow(i)
    plt.savefig('<location>.png')
    plt.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for i in np.array(lst).reshape(-1,2,2):
    plt.imshow(i, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()

    # other save image here
```